# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a sequence of uniform random variables to converge to 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Q: Formulate necessary and sufficient conditions for $\alpha_{i} < \beta_{i}$ such that independent (but not identically distributed) Uniform($\alpha_{i}, \beta_{i}$) variables $X_{i}$ converge to $0$.

a) in distribution

b) almost surely

From my workings I think that in both cases we need to have the $\alpha_{i_{s}}$ and $\beta_{i_{s}}$ both converge to $0$ so that the interval $[\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}]$ converges to the singular point $0$. This would imply that the CDF of $X_{i}$ converges to the step function: $0 \quad \text{for} \; x<0$ and $1 \quad \text{for} \; x\geq 0$ and hence $X_{i}$ converges to $0$ in distribution. Moreover, the event $\{ X_{i} \longrightarrow 0 \}$ must have probability $1$ and so we have almost sure convergence.

However this all feels way too simple. Also I would have suspected there to be more relaxed conditions on the parameters for convergence in distribution although I can't imagine any convergence working if the $\alpha_{i}$ and $\beta_{i}$ don't both go to $0$. I don't know if I'm missing something or just overthinking it.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

P.S. sorry for my slightly wonky LaTeX formatting, I'm still getting to grips with it! :)

Comment: It's true that if you have convergence in distribution to a constant that the convergence is also of the almost sure type. Don't confuse this with the convergence in mean where this does not hold per se ;)

Comment: @StanTendijck It is not true in general that if you have convergence in distribution to a constant then you have a.s. convergence. And for uniform distributions this is true due to boundedness. And convergence in mean also follows.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I see that if we have a.s. convergence then that implies weak convergence (convergence in distribution). What I'm wondering is are there any other conditions the ai and bi need to satisfy to imply either convergence? I.e. can we have weak convergence even if the ai and bi don't go to 0? Do we need an extra condition to guarantee a.s. convergence? I'm wondering if it's something to do with the limit of the CDF of the Xi but I might be barking up the wrong tree.